# coding conventions to tag user provided content (raising awareness of XSS vulnerabilities)

Tags: java, coding-style, xss

Do you know any good coding conventions that quickly warn a programmer that some variable (or config entry etc.) contains user provided content? I am trying to raise awareness of several attack vectors (like XSS) that are results of pasting unescaped content into HTML/JavaScript/HTTP.

For example:

```
String UserName_UNTRUSTED = readUrlParam("username");
```

**Added to clarify:**
I am specifically looking for Java coding conventions.

Answer (score 1):

One good option is like:

> All strings that come from the user must be stored in variables (or
>   database columns) with a name starting with the prefix "us" (for
>   Unsafe String). All strings that have been HTML encoded or which came
>   from a known-safe location must be stored in variables with a name
>   starting with the prefix "s" (for Safe string).

This is taken from a post regarding naming conventions from Joel, you can read full: 
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good source to communicate _why_ we need such a convention. But I was looking for more specific advice _how_ these coding conventions look like. Joel's article is more about the rational behind choosing any such convention.

Answer (score 1):

GWT uses classes like [SafeHtml](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml).

This uses Java's strong typing to help prevent unescaped user content from reaching the page, as long as the SafeHtml instances are created correctly. There are various methods for escaping, concatenating, and using safe constants. By using SafeHtml in a consistent way, it's easier to keep track of where variables came from, and what needs escaping.

The same idea could be used in general Java programs.